# Post Format Status

Tags: posts, admin, wp-admin, post-formats, post-status

I'm new at wordpress theme development. We inspected too many themes but didn't see any common culture at post format status. I wanted to ask how you're using this format, both front side and admin side ? Twitter embed code or just textarea or something, and if posible can you give some examples ?

Sorry about my bad English.

Thanks for replies

Comment: Sorry, but close voting as primarily opinion based as you are asking for something that has no concrete proof. Please see [ask] and [help] and learn which questions should be avoided

Comment: I know it can't be prooved but if too many people recommend your opinion; it can be labeled "common" as always. Don't get mad...

Comment: common has nothing to do with being right.... this question really doesn't belong here

Answer (score 1):

Post formats is an optional value added to WordPress posts which allows theme developers to define visual representation of a post. Theme developers can create themes with support for post formats. A number of post formats are available, however it is not possible for themes or plugins to introduce custom post formats. It is not necessary for theme developers to support all post formats.

```
Standard – The default post format
Aside – A note like post, usually styled without title.
Gallery – A gallery of images.
Link – A link to another site.
Image – An image or photograph
Quote – A quotation.
Status – Twitter like short status update
Video – A post containing video
Audio – An audio file.
Chat – A chat transcript
```

Comment: Answers should be more than plain links where someone might find his answer. Please file an [edit] and add the relevant info from the link inside your answer. Thank you

Comment: Standard is not a post format

Comment: Standard is the default post format of the WordPress Theme. I have checked it by using the twentytwelve theme in my wordpress installation. You may please check it once.

Comment: Standard is not a post format, it is a default given to all posts that does not have a post format set. Read my answer please

Comment: Yes, the same thing which i want to say. Standard is the default post format. My sentence might be not correct.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

From comments, it seems I've missed the actual purpose here

Here is an update:

There is no way to tell that or to know that. Every theme is unique and how a specific user uses a post format is also unique.

If you read my answer, status is used to display statusses like twitter. So in `content-status.php` you would have just maybe `the_excerpt()`.

When you write a post, you would write something like this in the content editor

> I'm listening to Metallica, drinking whiskey

and select the status format. In your front end you will see the post, and only the excerp will display, no title, post meta, no nothing, just like it does on twitter

### ORIGINAL POST

### WHAT IS POST FORMATS

[Post formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) are just terms from the build in [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)  `post_format` like categories and tags for the build in taxonomies `category` and `post tag`

Post formats lets you set different layouts and style for different formats. What this means is that you can have videos, galleries and normal post on the same page, each with a different layout without doing something extra.

To understand that, you need to know which formats are available and how they are used to display posts differently according to the specific format

### POST FORMATS

- video -> `post-format-video` -> widely used template: `content-video.php` -> To display videos
- audio -> `post-format-audio` -> widely used template: `content-audio.php` -> To display audio files
- aside -> `post-format-aside` -> widely used template: `content-aside.php` -> Display short messages in the same manner as messages on social networks like facebook without a title
- chat -> `post-format-chat` -> widely used template: `content-chat.php` -> Display chat like posts in the same way as on social networks like wechat and whattsapp
- gallery -> `post-format-gallery` -> widely used template: `content-gallery.php` -> Displays gallery posts
- link -> `post-format-link` -> widely used template: `content-link.php` -> Displays links to external sites
- image -> `post-format-image` -> widely used template: `content-image.php` -> Displays single attachment images
- status -> `post-format-status` -> widely used template: `content-status.php` -> Displays status updte messages in the same way as twitter
- quote -> `post-format-quote` -> widely used template: `content-quote.php` -> Displays quotes, like daily quotes or rhymes if you wish

As you can see, post formats also group posts together as any other taxonomy, and these posts within the same post format can be styled in the same way but it can have a different styling to other post formats

### FEW NOTES ON POST FORMATS

- Standard is not a post format, it is simply a name given to posts that has no post format assigned to it. This is any normal post. The widely used template for these posts is `content.php`
- You cannot add any more post formats to the nine above
- `post_format` is a non hierarchichal taxonomy, which means that its terms cannot have child terms
- Themes does not support post formats by default and has to be added with [`add_theme_support()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Formats) where you can also choose which formats you want and need to include
- Post formats, like any other taxonomy are assigned to posts only, not pages, so the post format meta box will only be available in the post editor screen.

### HOW IT WORKS

When a post is created, or edited for that matter, the post can be assigned to a post format which will control how the post will be displayed in the front end. For instance, if you add a gallery to the post, you can select the galary post format in the post format meta box, for vidoe posts, select the video post format. The post format meta box is set by default to standard, so any post that you don't select a post format will be set to standard

For this to work, you need to have the appropriate templates as described in the nine post formats under *widely used template*. Wordpress will then choose the correct template to display the post according to its format.

You need to however change your loop in your template files to `get_template_part('content', get_post_format());` and move your loop to the specific templates where you will need to style theme accordingly to your liking

### END RESULT

If you have 4 posts on your home page, one standard, 2 video post and one gallery post, Wordpress will load `content.php` for the standard post, `content-video.php` for the video posts and `content-gallery.php`  in order to display these posts to your desired styling

### CONCLUSION

Post formats are just a means to keep a uniform style between posts which has the same chataristics, and have a style different that other posts that does not share these chataristics. To close this, activate one of the bundled themes, and go play around with post formats on your local install. Also dig into these themes and see exactly how they utilize post formats

Comment: Thanks for comment Pieter but I already knew these... I want to learn just "status" post format and if you're gettin' a text like twitter or embed code or tweet's id or what...

Comment: It depends on how you style your `content-status.php` and what you add in that file. Please reread my answer.

Comment: Dear Pieter, as I said, I know all of them. Single, content, archive etc... My question is what is "common" ? What is user's habits on status format. What are they using status format for ? An embedding or just a textarea (in metas or custom fields) or what. Thanks for your time

Comment: Add my comment as an edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks for update Pieter. I'm not accepting it yet for getting another persons experiences and comments. 'll accept if your answer is mostly upvoted or only answer :)> Thanks aganin and good to hear "whiskey in the jar" :P